# how to switch intent function depend upon activity

Tags: android

how can i switch the function depend upon the parent activity i have  two case for which i want to switch between function.my function is related to sms otp verification.

case 1. when user is getting registered function is verifying otp and activating  the user.

case2: when user forgot their password they will generate a new otp to reset password.

here is my function code

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    // SqLite database handler
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());
    // Fetching user details from sqlite
    HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();


    if (intent != null) {
        String otp = intent.getStringExtra("otp");
        String phone = user.get("phone");
        verifyOtp(otp,phone);

    }
}
```

now i want to make it like

```
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        // SqLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());
        // Fetching user details from sqlite
        HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();


  if (intent != null) {
      String otp = intent.getStringExtra("otp"); //this coming from sms receiver 

    //from here i want to switch if parent activity is register activity below function should run


  String phone = user.get("phone");
  verifyOtp(otp,phone);


    // if parent activity  if forgot password activity the below function should run

    String phone = session.getmobileno();
    verifyfpass(otp,phone)

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by parent activity you mean from where you are launching the intent, then you can add another parameter within the intent to tell from where the intent has been sent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("from", "RegisterActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

And then in the handleIntent function, you can just check this variable's value, and perform your function such.

```
if (intent.hasExtra("from")) {
     String from = intent.getStringExtra("from");
     if (from.equals("RegisterActivity")) {
           //verifyotp
     } else if (from.equals("ForgotParentActivity")) {
          //verifyfpass
     }
}
```

However, if you want to check the activity you're present in right now, then you can use the `instanceof` property.

```
if (this instanceof RegisterActivity) {
     //verifyotp
} else if (this instanceof ForgotParentActivity)) {
     //verifyfpass
}
```

Answer (score 0):

at parent activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("from", "RegisterActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

final answer main activity
     @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

```
        pref = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        // SqLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());
        // Fetching user details from sqlite
        HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();

        if (intent != null) {
            if (intent.hasExtra("from")) {
                String from = intent.getStringExtra("from");
                if (from.equals("RegisterActivity")) {

                    String otp = intent.getStringExtra("otp");
                    String phone = user.get("phone");
                    verifyOtp(otp, phone);
                } else if (from.equals("Forgotpass")) {
                    String otp = intent.getStringExtra("otp");
                    String phone = pref.getMobileNumber();
                    verifyfpass(otp,phone);
                }


            }


        }
    }
```